# pyQt How to prevent QWebEngine from freezing

Tags: python, pyqt, freeze, qthread

I have a Gui that only contains a QWebEngineView, the user interactive functions are written in html and javascript.

At first my app:

```
# Create an application
app = QApplication([])

win = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()

# Create and fill a QWebView
view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath('templates/index.html')))

# Create a channel
channel = QWebChannel()
handler = CallHandler()
channel.registerObject('bridge', handler) # i called my channel 'bridge' so i can communicate with pyQt slots in my WebEngine

# Register channel
view.page().setWebChannel(channel)

# Add the QWebView to the layout
layout.addWidget(view)

win.setLayout(layout)
win.setWindowTitle('Test')
win.setMinimumSize(1280, 720)

# Show the window
win.show()

# Run the app
app.exec_()
```

The problem is when i call a method of my CallHandler class in my JS code the Gui freezes until the method has finished. My excpectation would be to show the dom with a loading spinner while python code is running and after finishing i would hide the spinner. Here is the call of the method in javascript:

[image]

```
connectedCallback() {
  console.log("custom element inserted into DOM.");

  // append template to custom element
  const tmpl = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#main-window');
  this.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));

  // backend listener
  if(window.hasOwnProperty("bridge")) {
      window.bridge.statistic_table_data_to_client.connect((data, that) => this.initStatisticTable(data, this));
      window.bridge.games_table_data_to_client.connect((data, that) => this.initGamesTable(data, this));

      $(".spinner").toggle();
      window.bridge.collect_games_table_data(); // this is the call to a pyQt slot
      $(".spinner").toggle();
  }
}
```

My CallHandler:

```
class CallHandler(QObject):

    @pyqtSlot()
    def collect_games_table_data(self):
        time.sleep(10) # after this command the gui isn't freezed anymore
```

I tried `QThread`, `app.processEvents()` and `QEventLoop` but i think i used it in a wrong way.
Can someone helpe me please?

Comment: You should not use such a large delay in a GUI, you have to handle it differently. Maybe you should use a javascript timer.

Comment: The sleep is only for demonstrating the problem